# How to count symbols before '.' symbol and split entire char[] into 2 arrays in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, binary, hex, octal

I want my function to read one char[] and split it into 2 arrays. Both arrays would be one big number, first array is for that number int value and second one is for double values. I must use 2 arrays because this number can be binary, decimal, octal or hex.

```
void Read(int place[], int &size, int &type, int placedot[], int &sizedot, int &typedot) 
{
    char reader[limit];

    cin >> reader;

    size = 1;

    while (reader[size] == '.' || size != strlen(reader)) 
    {
        size++;
        cout << "LOL";
    }

    cin >> type;
    cout << size;

    typedot = type;

    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++) 
    {
        switch (reader[i]) 
        {
            case '0': place[i] = 0; break;
            case '1': place[i] = 1; break;
            case '2': place[i] = 2; break;
            case '3': place[i] = 3; break;
            case '4': place[i] = 4; break;
            case '5': place[i] = 5; break;
            case '6': place[i] = 6; break;
            case '7': place[i] = 7; break;
            case '8': place[i] = 8; break;
            case '9': place[i] = 9; break;
            case 'A': place[i] = 10; break;
            case 'B': place[i] = 11; break;
            case 'C': place[i] = 12; break;
            case 'D': place[i] = 13; break;
            case 'E': place[i] = 14; break;
            case 'F': place[i] = 15; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the input and expected output?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the problem with your current code?

Comment: okey for example i want that if you type "3.124566" if would split it into 2 arrays - 3 and 124566 and get theyre length first one - 1 and second one 6

Comment: problem with current code is that it does not seperate those two arrays, and length of first array is both arrays length compined + '.' counts too

Comment: Reduce the switch statement, maybe replace.  Use `reader[i] - '0'` or `toupper(reader[i]) - 'A';`.

Comment: If you used `std::string`, then you could use one of its many search methods.

Comment: no, that switch statement is for converting hex symbols to int

Comment: thx i will try it

Comment: Is this some homework or just for fun? I mean, what are you allowed to use? Do you have to handle invalid input?

Comment: its homework, but im alowed to use anything, but i dont know a lot about c++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "3423432432.32445654576654578978905";
    std::string strInt;
    std::string strDec;

    int i = 0;

    while('.' != str[i])
        strInt += str[i++];

    for(++i; i < str.length(); i++)
        strDec += str[i];


    std::cout << strInt << std::endl << strDec << std::endl;

    // now you have the integer part and the decimal part as strings so convert each of them to int

    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```